# Close a hta file with a script

Tags: javascript, hta

I currently write a script which take a long moment to execute (more than 1 minute).
To make the user wait during the execution of the script, I launch an hta file with a message and a GIF

```
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
oExec = objShell.run('"mshta.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CaseWare\\Library\\ImportFEC\\Barre.hta"')
```

Then I execute all my script.
The problem is that I don't find a solution to close the hta file at the end of my script.
I try:

```
oExec.close();
oExec.Terminate();
oExec = null;
```

But nothing close the hta window and my GIF still running. I have an error with the two first solutions and the last one do nothing.

Thanks for your answer/comment.

Comment: Why not show and hide a message?

Comment: @mplungjan What do you mean ?

Comment: Run the script in the hta and show/hide a div

Answer (score 1):

I finnaly found a solution. 
Instead of using objShell.run I will use objShell.Exec

With this change, I can use oExec.Terminate(); to close the hta window

Thanks